# d3: Append caption/title to table

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have generated a table using d3.js. However somehow I cannot append a title or a caption to the table. I have tried append .append("text'), but then it would be positioned below the table. My latest try is .append('caption'), which also does not work.
Code is provided below:

```
    ====================================================*/

// Get the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Timestamp = parseDate(d.Timestamp);
  d.Position = +d.Position;
  d.Agency = +d.Agency;
});

function tabulate(data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select(".grid_intent").append("table").append("caption").text("Table");
  thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");
  // append the header row
  thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(column) {
      return column;
    });
  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr").data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");
  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll("td").data(function(row) {
      return columns.map(function(column) {
        return {
          column: column,
          value: row[column]
        };
      });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .attr("style", "font-family: Courier")
    .attr("colspan", "2")
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
  return table;
}

// render the table
var Pos_All_Agen = tabulate(data, ["Agentur", "Position"])
//Sort Table Accoring to Position
Pos_All_Agen.selectAll("tbody tr")
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.Position, b.Position);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have created a working fiddle so we could properly test, but in the blind, try this:

```
// Get the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Timestamp = parseDate(d.Timestamp);
  d.Position = +d.Position;
  d.Agency = +d.Agency;
});

function tabulate(data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select(".grid_intent");
  var caption = table.append("caption").text("Table");
  table.append("table");
  thead = table.append("thead"),
    tbody = table.append("tbody");
  // append the header row
  thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(column) {
      return column;
    });
  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr").data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr");
  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll("td").data(function(row) {
      return columns.map(function(column) {
        return {
          column: column,
          value: row[column]
        };
      });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .attr("style", "font-family: Courier")
    .attr("colspan", "2")
    .html(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
  return table;
}

// render the table
var Pos_All_Agen = tabulate(data, ["Agentur", "Position"])
//Sort Table Accoring to Position
Pos_All_Agen.selectAll("tbody tr")
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.Position, b.Position);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, next time i'll create a fiddle! Also unfortunately it didn't work :/

Comment: Please create a fiddle. Your code clearly requires specific elements to be present ('.grid_intent'), your problem might be deriving from a different issue. Unless you can replicate your issue there's not much we can do. I am confident that my code DOES work though, creating a <caption> element with its text before the table.